# React native crashing when building the app for debugging purpores

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-navigation

So I am building the debug app using the following commands

- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- `cd android`
- `./gradlew assembleDebug`

Now the app gets builds succesfully and also it get's installed.
And also the first screen works perfectly, but after going to the next screen it crashes

Here is the app link:  https://github.com/Hardik500/madri

Here is the set of packages I am using for the app

```
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^12.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-av": "^9.1.2",
    "expo-font": "^9.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.10.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.5.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.5.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-android-immersive-mode": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-animated-splash-screen": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-countdown-circle-timer": "^2.5.3",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-extra-dimensions-android": "^1.2.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-storage": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.13.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-use-gesture": "^9.1.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.3"
```

One possible issue that I thought was with `react-native-gesture-handler` package, but even after applying possible fixes I am not able to find the issue.

Are there any other packages that needs fixing, and if not how can I see the error for the build app, so I can see the error?

Comment: Can you post the error message? and did you try iOS? what machines are you using? Windows or Mac

Comment: I am using windows, and have tried to run the app only on my android phone.
Also as for errors, I can't see the errors as development works fine but the app crashes on build apk. Is there any way to get the error messages?

Comment: You can use react-native-crashlytics or Snagbug for getting errors in the release build. And your application crashes on launch or after some function?

Comment: My application crashes whenever I click the navigation button to go to the next screen i.e. from Home Screen (https://github.com/Hardik500/madri/blob/master/src/screens/Home.js) to Category Screen (https://github.com/Hardik500/madri/blob/master/src/screens/Category.js)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem was not with react-native-gesture handler but with the `Image` component from `react-native`, and for some reasons it was crashing the build APK but was working fine in development. So I had to replace that with `react-native-fast-image` and that seemed to fix the issue. Another fix which I found was that I was using shadows in the Animated Style Component from `react-native-reanimated`, and that also seemed to crash the build APK. So after making the necessary changes, the build seems to works fine.